# How not to use GOTO function here

Tags: programming-languages, goto

I know the global resentment of the goto logic.. but here it goes. Here is the case, say you have a function take in a status and decide which action you are going to take. This is a pseudo-code in python (as a joke.)

```
def function(status, condition, value):
    if(status == A) :
        goto actionA
    if(status == B) :
        goto actionB
    if(value > 1 or condition == C):
        goto actionA
    ...more conditions you got the idea.
    return;
  actionA:
     dosthA
     return
  actionB:
     dosthB
     return
  ...more actions
```

My question is, how would you implement such code?
It needs to be  easy to read. If later you decide to add an action or add an status or condition, you can do that with some confidence that it will not break earlier logic.

Comment: Use a function for actionA and call it instead of goto.

Comment: yeah, guess you are right, but goto works pretty nice here, I don't want to change the function just to avoid using goto keyword.

Comment: If your language allows a `switch (true) case status == A: ...`, I'd use that. Case grouping with fallthroughs would make that even more readable.

Answer (score 1):

You are jumping out of the conditional and down to your labels after every condition so only one of these can run.

In order to avoid duplicating the actionA code and avoid goto, you can just move your conditions around. dosthA will execute if status == A or if the status is not B (because then the other block will run) and the third condition matchs. Careful to preserve the behavior I get this:

```
def function(status, condition, value):
    if(status == A or (status != B && (value > 1 or condition == C))) :
        dosthA
        return
    if(status == B) :
        dosthB
        return
    ...more conditions you got the idea.
    return;
```

Also this is effectively a bunch of "else if"s or a switch since you're returning. Using "else if" or switch would probably increase clarity but in order to make the fewest changes an illustrate the actual important part of the answer I didn't make this into "else if"s.

By the way I'm a firm believer that the use of goto is a bad idea. It's worth reading Edsger W. Dijkstra's influential [Go To Statement Considered Harmful](http://www.u.arizona.edu/~rubinson/copyright_violations/Go_To_Considered_Harmful.html).